# Always run a processing thread if a message queue is not empty

Tags: java, multithreading

Whenever the server receives a message from a client, the message will be put in a queue. Multiple threads can input data in the queue, but only one thread should read/process from it at a time. As long as there are messages in the queue, the processing thread should be alive. How do I make this work?

If I put the processing logic in a synchronized method, and start a new thread calling this method for every request, won't it be a waste of resources having all those threads in memory, waiting their turn?

On the other hand, if I use a single processing thread, with each request trying to start it if it's not already running:

```
public void onMessage(String message) {
    addToQueue(message);
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (!processingThread.isAlive())
            processingThread.start();
    }
}

// processing thread
public void process() {
    while (true) {
        String message = queue.poll();
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (message == null)
                return;
        }
        // process message
    }
}
```

How can I make sure I don't run into this scenario:

1. Processing thread polls the queue for the next element. It gets the shared lock and enters a synchronized block. It checks and sees the element it read from the queue is `null`, so the queue is empty. **The thread releases the lock, but its `isAlive` flag hasn't been set to false yet.**
2. Client request arrives, adding a message in the queue. The receiving method gets the lock, and enters its synchronized block. The processing thread is still alive, so it doesn't need to be started. The method releases the lock.
3. The processing thread has now released the lock and dies.

In this case, there will be one unprocessed message in the queue. Can this scenario happen? As the bold sentence suggests, can the lock be released before the thread dies?

Answer (score 1):

This is a consumer/producer problem.  There is no need to stop/start the processing thread (consumer).  It can block, waiting for a message in the queue.  The client threads (producers) fill the queue and `notify()` the consumer thread which unblocks, removes the message and waits again.  Here is an example https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html.

Comment: But the `put` method is synchronized, so if I want to use multiple producers, they would have to wait their turn and I would lose the advantage of a concurrent queue. Is there some other way?

Comment: The put needs to be synchronized to prevent two producers from adding to the queue at the same time but a producer needs to wait only when the queue is full.  If the queue is not full, the producer adds its message, calls notifyAll and exits without waiting.

Comment: But I *do* want two producers to be able to add to the queue at the same time. And in this case, if two different producers try to call `put` at the same time, one of them has to wait for the other to return even if the queue is not full.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is possible to do that using the same queue but perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you need.  Concurrent processes that access a single resource have to be managed through some mechanism, otherwise, one process will clobber the data from the other or both end up locked.  The concurrent operation doesn't mean exactly at the same time, but rather orderly.  In the end, for a single processor, only one thing can happen at a time. The processor makes it look concurrent by switching threads.

Comment: Two concurrent processes that are both adding to the same queue don't need be synchronized and should be able to both add items simultaneously (see `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` in the docs, it's implemented with a non-blocking algorithm). And about reading, only one thread should read from a queue, so how can it end up locked?
About switching threads, I don't know much details, but what if I have multiple cores in my processor?

Comment: That is a neat algorithm.  I found the reference paper here: https://www.research.ibm.com/people/m/michael/podc-1996.pdf.  It works based on atomic operations and loops rather than blocks if there are two processes trying to add to the queue at the same time.  It looks like the consumer would need to loop/sleep if the queue was empty.  The producers could add to the queue simply though.  Good luck with it.